# Remove extra clickable area around links

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have two links that are positioned relatively to a div sized 100% height and 100% width of the viewport. I only want the text to be clickable. I thought using a block display for all link elements would fix this, but it is not working as expected. Where am I going wrong?

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

#container {
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 0;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#logocontainer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 25%;
}

#logocontainer a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#logocontainer img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#navcontainer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000000;
}

.store {
  font-family: neue-haas-grotesk-display, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding-top: 8%;
  position: absolute;
}

.videos {
  font-family: neue-haas-grotesk-display, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding-bottom: 8%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="navcontainer">
    <a href="/store" class="store">STORE</a>
    <a href="/last-seen" class="videos">VIDEOS</a>
  </div>

  <div id="logocontainer">
    <a href="/"> <img src="//placehold.it/200x100" alt="Logo." /> </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: If you want text to only be clickable then remove `<a href="">` tag from the img

Comment: To clarify, the image is also a link and clickable that's okay. This is regarding the two links 'VIDEOS' and 'STORE', the clickable area for those links are too large. They should only be clickable on the actual text.

Comment: Understood. You can try `<div class="store"><a href="/store"> STORE</a></div>`

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you have a good reason to use `position: absolute` on your `.store` and `.videos` elements. My gut tells me there is a better way to structure your elements that would make the following answer irrelevant. However, if you do have a good reason for using `position: absolute` on those elements, you need to ensure their heights do not result in elements overlapping and margin is used instead of padding. This is what's happening in your current fiddle.  To solve:

1. Remove `bottom: 0` from `.store` (to prevent it from extending to the bottom of the viewport, and thereby overlapping other elements.)
2. Change `padding-top` to `margin-top` on `.store`. Padding affects the "clickable" region of elements, margin does not.
3. Change `padding-bottom` to `margin-bottom` on `.videos`. Same reason as 2.
4. Make links children of parents with `text-align: center`. Alternatively, you could also use `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%)` without making the `a`s children.

https://jsfiddle.net/jboneca/ek1uy28o/8/

Comment: This worked great! The only issue is that there is still clickable area to the left and right of the two links. Some type of width issue?

Comment: @JohnSmith see updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jboneca/ek1uy28o/8/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `padding` use `margin`, and instead of displaying the links full width just use `text-align: center` on the parent:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

#container {
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 0;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#logocontainer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 25%;
}

#logocontainer a {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#logocontainer img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#navcontainer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000000;
}

.store {
  font-family: neue-haas-grotesk-display, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 8%;
}

.videos {
  font-family: neue-haas-grotesk-display, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-style: normal;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 8%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="navcontainer">
    <a href="/store" class="store">STORE</a>
    <a href="/last-seen" class="videos">VIDEOS</a>
  </div>

  <div id="logocontainer">
    <a href="/">
      <img src="//placehold.it/200x100" alt="Logo." />
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Note that your image won't behave as a link because you haven't set a height on it. Generally this is a bad way of going about building whatever you've got here; it's brittle and non-responsive. Consider using flexbox (`display: flex`) or similar to achieve a similar presentation.

This is what I would recommend instead:

```css
.container {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a + a {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="//placehold.it/200x100" />
  </a>
  <a href="#">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Prior to adding these two navigation links, my image does behave as a link. The width is responsively set to be 25% of 100% of the viewport. The problem is that the two navigation links' parent div (#navcontainer) is set to 100% height and that div is overlapping the image and its link. Unfortunately, because of how an unrelated animation is set up, I need the navigation links to be position on top of the logo, so I cannot simply place the logo and its link above the #navcontainer. Do you know how to fix this? To see the issue, simply remove the #navcontainer and the image link will then work.

Comment: @JohnSmith This is why I suggested you consider using flexbox. Using discrete positioning in a relatively sized parent will invariably produce edge cases and bugs like this. Instead you could have the entire thing working with a simple `display: flex; flex-direction: column; justify-content: space-between;` on the parent container.